# Magento 1.9 : Add value to file type custom option when adding product to cart programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, addtocart, file-upload

I am calling `$cart->addProduct($product, $params);` for adding product to cart. Where, `$product` is product collection  & `$params` is as follows as received from product page.

```
   Array
(
    [uenc] => aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tYWdlbnRvMTkvaW5kZXgucGhwL3Rlc3QtY2F0ZWdvcnkvdGVzdC1ncm91cGVkLXNpbXBsZS5odG1sP19fX1NJRD1V
    [product] => 1
    [form_key] => TmdkzWPP9ClLclJC
    [related_product] => 
    [options_1_file_action] => save_new
    [options_1_file] => test.png
    [options] => Array
        (
            [3] => fafasf
            [2] => 2
        )

    [qty] => 3
)
```

Everything is working fine except the file type custom option value is not getting added.
Thanks in advance!!!